Distribution of arithmetic variance of cumulative sums of normally distributed variables.
If I have $N$ random variables normally distributed $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ it is a well-known result that $\sum_{n=0}^N(X_n - \bar{X})^2 \sim \sigma^2\chi^2_{N-1}$, where $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N X_n$.
Is there any known distribution for a similar operation on the cumulative sum of $X_n$s? i.e.:
Take $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $Y_k = \sum_{n=0}^kX_n$. What is the distribution of $\sum_{k=0}^N(Y_k - \bar{Y})^2$, where $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^N Y_k$?
